# javascript signalR ignore invalid cert

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1, signalr.client

I'm working on a .netcore 2.1 website that uses javascipt to connect to signalR hub by https.
I managed to connect to the hub, but then i get an error:

```
Invalid cert authority
```

In my dev. environment I can bypass this, however it would be great if someone could provide a javascript example that I can use in production.

So far I have tried this:

```
 init: function () {
                    LayoutHubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .withUrl("@AppSettings.Value.BaseUrl.PhatraOnlineSignalR", opts =>
                        {
                           opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (x) => new HttpClientHandler
                            {
                              ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                            };
                        })
                         .build();
                },
```

But it is still not working. So any suggestion would be great and some example would be perfect.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in JavaScript, as it is managed by the browser. Being able to do that would be a terrible security flaw.

Comment: Why do you not use Blazor for your frontend, if you are mainly used to C# anyways?

Comment: @lucniner Our Team uses javascript frontend from the start. can't change it on my own.

Comment: @RicardoPeres Thank you. I look at Microsoft doc and I think your right I try to find another way around.